# Getting access denied when trying to delete S3 bucket as admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, admin

I am getting Access Denied when trying to delete s3 bucket, I am the admin and have AdminFullAccess.

Comment: Are you using Terraform? Is the bucket empty?

Comment: How are you "trying to delete" the bucket? Does the bucket have a Bucket Policy? It is possible that a `Deny` policy is overriding your permissions, which could come from the Bucket Policy or another IAM policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check (or delete) your bucket policy